# how to pass boolean value by emitting events from one component to other - vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my application, there is a parent Product page component consists of two child components. The basic structure is like

**Parent(ProductPage)**

```
<template>
  ....
   <div><ProductListTable /></div>
   <div><EditActionComponent /></div>
  .... 
</template>
```

In EditActionComponent, one edit button is there. ProductListTable is having products list where  on each row click one edit modal will open.

So i want when i click edit button in edit action component then only row click will be enabled in product list table component.

**EditActionComponent**

```
methods:{
    onEditAction(){
      this.editable = true;
      this.actionButtonsToShow = false;
      this.editTextToshow = true;
      this.$emit('editable',this.editable)
    }
 }
```

**ProductListTable**

```
methods: {
  onRowClick() {
    if(this.editable) { // i need this boolean value here
        // modal open logic
     }
   }
}
```

So how to pass boolean value one child component to other child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're already emitting an event from your `EditActionComponent` you can get the boolean value by adding event listener for editable

eg: `<EditActionComponent v-on:editable="callbackFunction">`

in your `ProductPage` component, you create the `callbackFunction(val)` method to get the boolean value and store it in your `data`.

```
// ProductPage Component
data: () => ({
     editable: false
}),
methods: {
    callbackFunction(val) {
         this.editable = val;
    }
}
```

then you bind the variable to your `ProductListTable` component (assuming you have the `editable` props declared).

```
<ProductListTable :editable="editable" />
```